# How to get records from SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

i have to SQL server 2008 tables as below

**Table A**

```
ID          int         Not Null (primary ID)
No          int         NULL
Value       int         NULL
Flag        nchar(10)   NULL
```

**Table B**

```
ID          int         Not Null (primary ID)
No          int         NULL
Value       int         NULL
Flag        nchar(10)   NULL
```

and i Have below data in table A

```
ID     No      Value   Flag
1      1        12      1         
2      1        12      1         
3      1        25      1         
4      2        120     1         
5      3        36      2         
6      2        120     2         
7      6        1       1         
8      2        10      1         
9      6        10      2         
10     1        25      2         
11     2        120     1
```

and there no records in table B
 when i write below statement

```
SELECT     dbo.A.No, SUM(dbo.A.Value) AS [IN], SUM(ISNULL(dbo.B.Value, 0)) AS OUT
FROM         dbo.A LEFT OUTER JOIN
                      dbo.B ON dbo.A.NO = dbo.B.NO
WHERE     (dbo.A.Flag = N'1')
GROUP BY dbo.A.No
```

I am getting below result

```
No      IN      OUT
1       49       0
2       250      0
6       1        0
```

When I add `WHERE     (dbo.A.Flag = N'1') AND (dbo.B.Flag = N'1')`

nothing is coming..

my question is How to get records from table B as 0 when B not contains records or not find B.Id

**UPDATE :**
When i have data in table B Then records are coming.

Comment: what were you expecting the output? Flag form B as well?

Comment: `outer` tables should be filtered in join, not where.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Imran,
I think the below `sql` will help you.

```
SELECT      A.No, 
            SUM(A.Value) AS [IN], 
            SUM(ISNULL(B.Value, 0)) AS [OUT]
FROM        dbo.A A 
LEFT JOIN   dbo.B B ON A.No = B.No AND B.Flag = N'1'
WHERE       A.Flag = N'1'
GROUP BY    A.No
```

Comment: Thanks... its Working..I was wrong in Question, so I Corrected Question and Answer

Answer (score -1):

Try using this condition :-

```
WHERE (dbo.A.Flag = N'1') AND (dbo.B.Flag = ISNULL(N'1',0));
```

This might be helpful to you.